# Best performing way of trimming the first and last instances of strings from another string?

Tags: c#, string, performance

I'm trying to trim the first instance of variable length strings from the start and end of another string, and am struggling to figure out an ideal way to do this without iterating over the string too many times.

For example, suppose I have

```
public string ParseValue(string value, string trimFromStart, string trimFromEnd)
{
    // ??
}
```

and I call

```
var value = ParseValue("AAABBBCCCAAABBB", "AAAB", "BB");
```

then I would expect the end result to be `value = "BBCCCAAB"`

What is the best performing way of accomplishing this in terms of speed and memory usage?

Comment: You say variable length, but do you know _what_ you're trying to trim when you go to trim it? Or is it a pattern/unknown?

Comment: You mean first 4 characters and last 2 characters which can be anything?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel _"the values I am trimming off of [sic] are a variable size"_

Comment: @BradChristie The strings to trim are built using String.Format(), and the parameters can be of a variable length.

Comment: @Rachel do you mean the `AAAB` is just a variable string?

Comment: @KingKing Yes, the length of the strings to trim off the ends is variable.

Comment: @Rachel still a little confused, it's not just the length, even the string value, for example, it can be `ABCD`, `ABDEF`, ... if it's just the length, there must be some rule to determine its value, for example, `AB`, `AAB`, `AAAB`, ...?

Comment: @KingKing See the update to my question... hopefully that can help clarify

Comment: What do you do with overlapping cases? For example, given "ABCD" and trim start "ABC" and trim end "CD", what should you get? "D" or ""? (I'm guessing the latter, but always worthwhile making sure)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair That's part of my problem. Ideally it should trim both if they both exist (without overlapping), and return a null value and log the problem if they don't.

Comment: I think in such a case, we have to perform one of the trim first.

Comment: Also, how performant do you need it to be? I mean, have you attempted a naive implementation that is _functionally_ correct (covering all these mentioned edge cases, ideally with unit tests) and found it's causing too much of a measurable bottleneck? If so, can you post that implementation and give us an idea of "how much" faster and/or memory efficient it must be? EDIT: Or is this just an exercise to see what is possible?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I was actually have troubles figuring out the exact syntax for this, and was hoping someone would be able to provide a decent-performing answer without too many iterations over the string object. I think I may have figured out something that works though, with the help of some of the answers posted here.

Comment: Do you consider regex based solution or worried about performance?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I did consider it, but I was concerned about performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already answered, but here's an implementation (which probably could be tweaked) that covers a few more edge cases.

```
public string ParseValue(string value, string trimFromStart, string trimFromEnd)
{
    int valueLength = value.Length;
    int trimStartAmount = value.StartsWith(trimFromStart) 
        ? trimFromStart.Length 
        : 0;

    int trimFromEndIndex = valueLength;
    int trimEndAmount = 0;

    if (value.EndsWith(trimFromEnd))
    {
        trimFromEndIndex = valueLength - trimFromEnd.Length;
        trimEndAmount = trimFromEnd.Length;
    }

    if (trimStartAmount >= trimFromEndIndex)
        return "";

    if (trimStartAmount == 0 && trimEndAmount == 0)
        return value;

    return value.Substring(trimStartAmount, valueLength - trimStartAmount - trimEndAmount);
}
```

Tests:

```
Assert.AreEqual("C", ParseValue("ABCDE", "AB", "DE"));
Assert.AreEqual("ABC", ParseValue("ABCDE", "ABCDEF", "DE"));
Assert.AreEqual("DE", ParseValue("ABCDE", "ABC", "ABCDEF"));
Assert.AreEqual("", ParseValue("ABCDE", "ABC", "CDE"));
Assert.AreEqual("", ParseValue("ABCDE", "ABC", "DE"));
Assert.AreEqual("BBCCCAAAB", ParseValue("AAABBBCCCAAABBB", "AAAB", "BB"));
```

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18495480/1269654) fails on tests 2, 3, 4, and throws exceptions when the two strings overlap.

Comment: Sorry but `ParseValue("AAAABAC", "A", "C");` returns `AAABA`. I would expect `BA` (as the word `TRIM` implies)

Comment: @QtX Actually that was not what I requested. I specifically want to only trim the first instances of the string from the ends, so would expect a return value of `AAABA`. I may have removed that information during one of my question edits, but it should be part of the current version. Thanks Chris, this is a nice implementation that counts for all the edge cases :)

Comment: @QtX: Hrrrm, yeah, I suppose. But honestly, reading the question it seems ambiguous to me if she wanted to remove only the first occurrence of the string, or to emulate the `TrimStart`/`TrimEnd` behaviour which removes _all_ occurrences in a row.

Comment: @Rachel -1 `I may have removed that information during one of my question edits` I see `40K reps` questions are so,

Comment: @QtX: My answer has the same results as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18495488/1269654), and the algorithm isn't _that_ much different, _and_ uses one less `Substring` call when both a start and end trim are needed. Can you indicate to me how my answer is not considered "correct" so I may fix it?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair See my first comment. *`Sorry but ParseValue("AAAABAC", "A", "C"); returns AAABA. I would expect BA (as the word TRIM implies)`* And I also commented *`@Habib I saw it. And I still think TRIM should work as I think. I'll leave my comments and downvotes for future readers not to confuse them`*

Comment: @QtX: Rachel has indicated that this is _not_ desired behaviour. Secondly, King King's first answer produces _your_ expected result, but fails for `ParseValue("ABCDE", "ABC", "CDE")` (as he acknowledges). His second example works identical to mine with the recursive code commented (so failing _your_ test), and does work with that commented code restored. So would you like me to correct my answer based on _your interpretation_ of the answer, or on what Rachel intended to ask? (Or would you recommend we edit/update her question to add the clarification instead?)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I am not interested, what @Rachel wants when mentioning `Trim` in the question. We all know how it behaves and your code doesn't work for `ParseValue("AAAABAC", "A", "C");` according to me. So I downvoted it. People thinking different from me can of course upvote it. I am sorry but a vague question results in so many silly comments/answer etc.

Comment: @QtX: I disagree. Reading the question (and its edits) in plain language does not necessarily indicate the intent to remove multiple instances of the string nor duplicate the repeating behaviour of `String.TrimStart(char[])`. Seeing as most people perceived/read the question as removing a single string I think indicates that this is how it will be most viewed (especially after the most recent edits to the question). Downvote the question, sure; it _should_ be downvoted (at least in its early forms, perhaps after the edits it can be restored).

Comment: @QtX: Thats why so many comments were made to _clarify_ the question. After these comments, the intended results and correct answers should be obvious now; emulating `String.TrimStart(char[])` is _not_ correct and should not be treated as correct. I agree, on the whole though, ambiguous **questions** _should_ be downvoted. EDIT: But _correct_ answers which do not align with an incorrect interpretation of the question should not be downvoted.

Comment: I am accepting this answer over King Kong's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18495488/302677) simply because it doesn't reassign the string so many times. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's the best:

```
public string ParseValue(string value, string trimFromStart, string trimFromEnd)
{
  var s = value.StartsWith(trimFromStart) ? value.Substring(trimFromStart.Length) : value;
  s = s.EndsWith(trimFromEnd) ? s.Substring(0,s.Length-trimFromEnd.Length) : s;      
  return s == value ? s : ParseValue(s, trimFromStart, trimFromEnd);
}
```

If you want to deal with the case for example to make `ParseValue("ABCDE","ABC","CDE") == ""`, this code works OK, looks like that you don't want to trim twice, so I commented out the `recursive code` in this version:

```
public string ParseValue(string value, string trimFromStart, string trimFromEnd){
   bool startsWith = value.StartsWith(trimFromStart);
   bool endsWith = value.EndsWith(trimFromEnd);
   int startLength = trimFromStart.Length;
   int endLength = trimFromEnd.Length;
   if (startsWith && endsWith && value.Length <= startLength + endLength) return "";
   var s = startsWith ? value.Substring(startLength) : value;
   s = endsWith ? s.Substring(0, s.Length - endLength) : s;
   return s;// == value ? s : ParseValue(s, trimFromStart, trimFromEnd);
}
```

Comment: `"AAAABA".TrimStart('A');` returns `AB`. So a string solution should work similarly. Pattern may repeat many times at the beginning and end.

Comment: @QtX I didn't think that's what the OP wants, if so just call the method recursively.

Comment: @QtX is there any compilation problem?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair thanks, you're right, we can perform only `Substring` after calculating all the needed indices.

Comment: @KingKing: Heh, I don't _quite_ remember what I commented. I did however botch one of my tests (I had misread part of your answer which dealt with the commented code). All in all, I like your answer, both of them; seems more reasonable in terms of understanding what's going on.